# The method findViewById(int) is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I am extending fragment and i get this error saying, the method `findViewById(int)` is undefined for the type Song.

The error appear for both my progress bar and webview on the findViewById.

```
public class Song extends Fragment{


    ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,


    Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, container, false);


    return myFragmentView;


    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


    final WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Browsery);


    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


    mWebView.loadUrl("....");


    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){



    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){


    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    });
```

Please i need help

Thank you.

Comment: Do the proper editing before posting.

Comment: View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, container, false);


   


    progressBar = (ProgressBar)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 return myFragmentView;

change like this u hav 2 use the view . in fragment as its inflating a layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are finding view in wrong way, append `view object` while findViewById as like below:

```
 progressBar = (ProgressBar)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
 final WebView mWebView = (WebView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Browsery);
```

Comment: @ Robinhood when i add myFragmentView to the second its shows another error saying code unreachable

Comment: perform initializationof view and clickevent within `onCreateView`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but how am i suppose to do this, am still a rookie

Comment: yessss!!!!! It worked, thank you so much Robinhood you the men, thank you it worked like a charm, am most grateful

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing like this.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.XYZ);
```

Comment: @ Rajnikant when i add getView() to the second its shows another error saying code unreachable –

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Song extends Fragment{


ProgressBar progressBar;


@Override


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,


Bundle savedInstanceState) {


View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, container, false);





progressBar = (ProgressBar)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);


final WebView mWebView = (WebView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Browsery);
 return myFragmentView;

mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);


mWebView.loadUrl("....");


mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){



public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){


progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

});
```

Comment: when i added myFragmentView to the second one and error shows up saying code unreachable

Answer (score 0):

you r returning `myFragmentView` before getting your `progressBar` and `webView`. your code should be modified as :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View myFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song, container, false);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    final WebView mWebView = (WebView)myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.Browsery);

     /// your code ....
     /// .......

    // this should be the last line of your onCreateView()
    return myFragmentView;
}
```